# Update mint & freeze authority for an NFT

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, spl-token, metaplex, metaplex-js

This is the command I'm using to update the authority of my NFT at address `9ZgNKyB7qoqpEeMmQqxg9MNJASCb5S9rc2sLN7ZbZ9w8`:

`spl-token authorize 9ZgNKyB7qoqpEeMmQqxg9MNJASCb5S9rc2sLN7ZbZ9w8 mint B3wYtZY9fLXB2oxfXdNaDEGBY8tsUP6X5YAQ5sRDiyn8`

When I run this, I get the error `owner not match`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you default keypair is 7gwDGBvtCJUmLrWu9cSyirBfMmMNqP9xfH8DrgKsMvpK.

You can check it by using:

```
solana address
```

and if you have the keypair somewhere else you can also call

```
spl-token authorize
```

with

```
-k yourKeyPair.json
```

Comment: Yes it is the same, then also getting this issue.

Comment: What are you actually planning to do? Looks like this is an nft so the max supply will be 1 any way and 7gwDGBvtCJUmLrWu9cSyirBfMmMNqP9xfH8DrgKsMvpK is the only wallet that would be able to update the meta data.

Comment: I'm trying to update the mint and freeze authority for the nft

Comment: Do I need to sign from mint authority key ? Or what exactly is the update authority? Is it required for updating metadata of the NFT?